# Change opacity of image in CachedNetworkImage Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I have multiple images.

I want **change the opacity** of the image with the imageUrl.

My goal is that when user click on a image, it change his opacity.

**My question is how to change the opacity while keeping the image ?**

My CachedNetworkImage :

```
         CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl : _getImageUrl(),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                errorWidget: (context, exception, stacktrace)
                {
                  return const Icon(Icons.warning);
                },
              )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `CachedNetworkImage` with `Opacity` widget and provide `opacity:x` based on your need.

```dart
double _opacity =.3;
 ......

Opacity(
  opacity: _opacity.
  child:CachedNetworkImage(...)
```

More about [`Opacity`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html).